# How to visualise a ribbon projected from a 3D line as "always facing forward"

Tags: windows, 3d, visualization, openinventor

We currently have a (curved) line made up of points in a 3D space (in open inventor, but the solution to this problem is likely to be non-product specific).

We want to draw a surface that describes a ribbon projected orthogonally from that line, and which always faces the camera as it rotates.

(e.g. the user will see the a ribbon that describes the curve of the line with the line itself as one of its sides, and then as we rotate around the scene, the ribbon will "rotate" about the line so that it is always always facing the user)

We have:

- The position and rotation of the camera
- The position of each point along the line

We thought a way to approach was, for each pair of adjacent points, to find the line that intersects the plane orthogonal to the camera and a plane orthogonal to the line between those points, and project a set distance along that line, but this didn't give us anywhere near the correct result. (malfunctioning code below).

Is this approach correct, and if so, what is wrong with the code below that should describe it?

If not, how do we achieve the core aim (ribbon always facing the user)?

```
SbVec3f getOuterPoint(SbVec3f p3, const float ribbon_width, float cosine, float sine)
{
    return SbVec3f(p3[0] + ribbon_width*cosine, p3[1] - ribbon_width*sine, p3[2]);
}

SbVec3f getOuterPoint(SbVec3f old_p3, SbVec3f other_point, const float ribbon_width)
{
    float oangle = atan2(old_p3[1] - other_point[1], old_p3[0] - other_point[0]);
    float ocosine = cosf(oangle);
    float osine = sinf(oangle);
    return getOuterPoint(old_p3, ribbon_width, ocosine, osine);
}

SbVec3f getOuterPoint(SbVec3f p0, SbVec3f p1, const float ribbon_width, SoCamera* camera)
{
    SbVec3f axis;
    float angle;
    SoSFRotation camera_rotation = camera->orientation;
    camera_rotation.getValue(axis, angle);
    //std::cout << axis[0] << " " << axis[1] << " " << axis[2] << ":" << angle << std::endl;

    const SbVec3f &camera_position = camera->position.getValue();

    SbVec3f camera_axis = axis;

    SbVec3f well_axis = p1 - p0;

    well_axis.normalize();
    camera_axis.normalize();

    float cam_constant[3] = { -p1[0], -p1[1], -p1[2] };
    float well_constant[3] = { -p1[0], -p1[1], -p1[2] };

    /*

    //float p1_constant = camera_axis[0] * p1[0] + camera_axis[1] * p1[1] + camera_axis[2] * p1[2]
    //  - (camera_axis[0] * camera_position[0] + camera_axis[1] * camera_position[1] + camera_axis[2] * camera_position[2]);

    //// X, Y, Z are unknown
    //float line_unknown = camera_axis[0] * X + camera_axis[1] * Y + camera_axis[2] * Z;

    // 
    //
    // camera_axis.x * (x - p1[0]) + camera_axis.y * (y - p1[1]) + camera_axis.z * (z - p1[2]) = 0      (1)
    // well_axis.x   * (x - p1[0]) + well_axis.y   * (y - p1[1]) + well_axis.z   * (z - p1[2]) = 0      (2)

    // let z become free variable t

    // camera_axis.x * (x - p1[0]) + camera_axis.y * (y - p1[1]) = - camera_axis.z * (t - p1[2]) 
    // well_axis.x   * (x - p1[0]) + well_axis.y   * (y - p1[1]) = - well_axis.z   * (t - p1[2]) 

    // camera_axis.x * (x - p1[0]) + camera_axis.y * (y - p1[1]) = - camera_axis.z * t - camera_axis.z * p1[2] 
    // well_axis.x * (x - p1[0]) + well_axis.y * (y - p1[1]) = - well_axis.z * t - well_axis.z * p1[2] 

    // camera_axis.x * x  + camera_axis.y * y  = - camera_axis.z * t - camera_axis.z * p1[2] + camera_axis.x  *p1[0] + camera_axis.y  * p1[1] (3)
    // well_axis.x * x  + well_axis.y * y  = - well_axis.z * t - well_axis.z * p1[2] + well_axis.x  *p1[0] + well_axis.y  * p1[1]               (4)

    (3) * well_axis.x:

    well_axis.x * camera_axis.x * x  + well_axis.x * camera_axis.y * y  = well_axis.x * ( - camera_axis.z * t - camera_axis.z * p1[2] + camera_axis.x  *p1[0] + camera_axis.y  * p1[1])

    (4) * camera_axis.x
    camera_axis.x * well_axis.x * x  + camera_axis.x * well_axis.y * y  = camera_axis.x * ( - well_axis.z * t - well_axis.z * p1[2] + well_axis.x  *p1[0] + well_axis.y  * p1[1])

    Subtracting
    well_axis.x * camera_axis.y * y - camera_axis.x * well_axis.y * y  = well_axis.x * ( - camera_axis.z * t - camera_axis.z * p1[2] + camera_axis.x  *p1[0] + camera_axis.y  * p1[1]) - camera_axis.x * ( - well_axis.z * t - well_axis.z * p1[2] + well_axis.x  *p1[0] + well_axis.y  * p1[1])

    (well_axis.x * camera_axis.y - camera_axis.x * well_axis.y) * y = well_axis.x * ( - camera_axis.z * t - camera_axis.z * p1[2] + camera_axis.x  *p1[0] + camera_axis.y  * p1[1]) - camera_axis.x * ( - well_axis.z * t - well_axis.z * p1[2] + well_axis.x  *p1[0] + well_axis.y  * p1[1])
    y = well_axis.x * ( - camera_axis.z * t - camera_axis.z * p1[2] + camera_axis.x  *p1[0] + camera_axis.y  * p1[1]) - camera_axis.x * ( - well_axis.z * t - well_axis.z * p1[2] + well_axis.x  *p1[0] + well_axis.y  * p1[1]) / (well_axis.x * camera_axis.y - camera_axis.x * well_axis.y)


    (3) * well_axis.y
    well_axis.y * camera_axis.x * x  + well_axis.y * camera_axis.y * y  = well_axis.y * ( - camera_axis.z * t - camera_axis.z * p1[2] + camera_axis.x  *p1[0] + camera_axis.y  * p1[1])
    (4) * camera_axis.y
    camera_axis.y * well_axis.x * x  + camera_axis.y * well_axis.y * y  = camera_axis.y * ( - well_axis.z * t - well_axis.z * p1[2] + well_axis.x  *p1[0] + well_axis.y  * p1[1])

    Subtracting
    x = well_axis.y * ( - camera_axis.z * t - camera_axis.z * p1[2] + camera_axis.x  *p1[0] + camera_axis.y  * p1[1]) - camera_axis.y * ( - well_axis.z * t - well_axis.z * p1[2] + well_axis.x  *p1[0] + well_axis.y  * p1[1]) / well_axis.y * camera_axis.x  - camera_axis.y * well_axis.x


    So:
    x = well_axis.y * ( - camera_axis.z * t - camera_axis.z * p1[2] + camera_axis.x  *p1[0] + camera_axis.y  * p1[1]) - camera_axis.y * ( - well_axis.z * t - well_axis.z * p1[2] + well_axis.x  *p1[0] + well_axis.y  * p1[1]) / (well_axis.y * camera_axis.x - camera_axis.y * well_axis.x)
    y = well_axis.x * ( - camera_axis.z * t - camera_axis.z * p1[2] + camera_axis.x  *p1[0] + camera_axis.y  * p1[1]) - camera_axis.x * ( - well_axis.z * t - well_axis.z * p1[2] + well_axis.x  *p1[0] + well_axis.y  * p1[1]) / (well_axis.x * camera_axis.y - camera_axis.x * well_axis.y)
    z = t


    x = ((well_axis.z * camera_axis.y - camera_axis.z * well_axis.y) * t
    - camera_axis.z * well_axis.y * p1[2]
    + camera_axis.x  * well_axis.y * p1[0]
    + well_axis.z * camera_axis.y * p1[2]
    - well_axis.x * camera_axis.y * p1[0] ) 
    / (well_axis.y * camera_axis.x - camera_axis.y * well_axis.x)

    y =  ( - camera_axis.z * well_axis.x * t - camera_axis.z * well_axis.x * p1[2] + camera_axis.x  * well_axis.x * p1[0] + camera_axis.y  * well_axis.x * p1[1] + well_axis.z * camera_axis.x * t + well_axis.z * camera_axis.x * p1[2] - well_axis.x  * camera_axis.x * p1[0] - well_axis.y * camera_axis.x * p1[1]) / (well_axis.x * camera_axis.y - camera_axis.x * well_axis.y)


    y =  ((well_axis.z * camera_axis.x - camera_axis.z * well_axis.x) * t 
    - camera_axis.z * well_axis.x * p1[2]
    + camera_axis.y  * well_axis.x * p1[1] 
    + well_axis.z * camera_axis.x * p1[2]
    - well_axis.y * camera_axis.x * p1[1])
    / (well_axis.x * camera_axis.y - camera_axis.x * well_axis.y)


    // Given these two equations, we now have a parameterised equation

    // (x,y,z) = (mt + a, nt + b, t) = (m, n, 1)t + (a + b + 0)
    // 
    // m = ((well_axis[2] * camera_axis[1] - camera_axis[2] * well_axis[1])) / (well_axis[1] * camera_axis[0] - camera_axis[1] * well_axis[0])
    // 
    // n = ((well_axis[2] * camera_axis[0] - camera_axis[2] * well_axis[0])) / (well_axis[0] * camera_axis[1] - camera_axis[0] * well_axis[1])
    // 
    // a = (- camera_axis[2] * well_axis[1] * p1[2] + camera_axis[0] * well_axis[1] * p1[0] + well_axis[2] * camera_axis[1] * p1[2] - well_axis[0] * camera_axis[1] * p1[0]) / (well_axis[1] * camera_axis[0] - camera_axis[1] * well_axis[0])
    // 
    // b = (- camera_axis[2] * well_axis[0] * p1[2] +camera_axis[1] * well_axis[0] * p1[1]  + well_axis[2] * camera_axis[0] * p1[2] - well_axis[1] * camera_axis[0] * p1[1]) / (well_axis[0] * camera_axis[1] - camera_axis[0] * well_axis[1])
*/

    float m = ((well_axis[2] * camera_axis[1] - camera_axis[2] * well_axis[1])) / (well_axis[1] * camera_axis[0] - camera_axis[1] * well_axis[0]);
    // 
    float n = ((well_axis[2] * camera_axis[0] - camera_axis[2] * well_axis[0])) / (well_axis[0] * camera_axis[1] - camera_axis[0] * well_axis[1]);
    // 
    float a = (-camera_axis[2] * well_axis[1] * p1[2] + camera_axis[0] * well_axis[1] * p1[0] + well_axis[2] * camera_axis[1] * p1[2] - well_axis[0] * camera_axis[1] * p1[0]) / (well_axis[1] * camera_axis[0] - camera_axis[1] * well_axis[0]);
    // 
    float b = (-camera_axis[2] * well_axis[0] * p1[2] + camera_axis[1] * well_axis[0] * p1[1] + well_axis[2] * camera_axis[0] * p1[2] - well_axis[1] * camera_axis[0] * p1[1]) / (well_axis[0] * camera_axis[1] - camera_axis[0] * well_axis[1]);

    float t = 2;

    return SbVec3f(m * t + a, n * t + b, t);
}

void setVertices(WellBore * pWell, SoVertexProperty * vertex_property, SoCamera* camera)
{
    int nPoints = pWell->nPoints;

    const float ribbon_width = 50.0f;

    int vertex_index = 0;
    int face_index = 0;

    int max_to_draw = nPoints;
    vertex_property->vertex.deleteValues(max_to_draw);

    SbVec3f on_well0x = pWell->points[1];
    SbVec3f in_space0x = getOuterPoint(pWell->points[0], on_well0x, ribbon_width, camera);

    for (int i = 0; i < max_to_draw - 1; ++i)
    {
        SbVec3f on_well0 = pWell->points[i];
        SbVec3f on_well1 = pWell->points[i + 1];

        SbVec3f in_space1 = getOuterPoint(on_well0, on_well1, ribbon_width, camera);

        vertex_property->vertex.set1Value(vertex_index + 0, in_space0x);
        vertex_property->vertex.set1Value(vertex_index + 1, on_well0x);
        vertex_property->vertex.set1Value(vertex_index + 2, on_well1);
        vertex_property->vertex.set1Value(vertex_index + 3, in_space0x);
        vertex_property->vertex.set1Value(vertex_index + 4, in_space1);

        vertex_index += 5;

        on_well0x = on_well1;
        in_space0x = in_space1;
    }
}

void cameraDebug(SoXtViewer * myViewer, WellBore* pWell)
{
    SoCamera* camera = myViewer->getCamera();

    SbVec3f camera_position = camera->position.getValue();
    //std::cout << camera_position[0] << " " << camera_position[1] << " " << camera_position[2] << std::endl;

    SbVec3f axis;
    float angle;
    SoSFRotation camera_rotation = camera->orientation;
    camera_rotation.getValue(axis, angle);
    //std::cout << axis[0] << " " << axis[1] << " " << axis[2] << ":" << angle << std::endl;

    SoNode* node = SoNode::getByName(SbName("points"));
    SbString str;
    SoVertexProperty* vertices = static_cast<SoVertexProperty*>(static_cast<SoVertexShape*>(node)->vertexProperty.getValue());
    //std::cout << vertices->vertex.getNum() << str << std::endl;

    setVertices(pWell, vertices, camera);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A narrowly specific answer to your question is relatively easy. The approach stated in your question sounds correct, but the code you provided seems way too complicated...
Briefly: You have one vector defined by two consecutive points in the ribbon path and a second vector defined by the camera direction. The vector you need is just the cross-product of these two vectors. The camera position is irrelevant, only the direction matters.  Using Open Inventor you have to compute the camera direction using the default direction vector and the current camera orientation like this:

```
// Camera (reverse) direction vector
SbVec3f defVec(0,0,1), camVec;
const SbRotation& camRot = camera->orientation.getValue();
camRot.multVec( defVec, camVec );
camVec.normalize();
```

If 'verts' is the ribbon path, then for each segment of the path you have two coordinates and can compute two additional offset coordinates such that the four coordinates define a rectangular polygon that faces the user, something like:

```
SbVec3f ribVec, orthoVec;
for (int i = 0; i < numSegs; ++i) {
  ribVec = verts[i+1] - verts[i];
  ribVec.normalize();
  orthoVec = camVec.cross(ribVec);
  orthoVec.normalize();
  verts2[i*4  ] = verts[i];  // i*4 because 4 verts per segment
  verts2[i*4+1] = verts[i+1];
  verts2[i*4+2] = verts[i+1] + ribbonWidth * orthoVec;
  verts2[i*4+3] = verts[i  ] + ribbonWidth * orthoVec;
```

Now you can work on the harder part -- how to handle the "joints" between these polygons so the ribbon looks nice...